# Driving a truck from UK to Africa for charity

Tags: uk, driving, africa

Some time ago, I saw a TV programme about volunteers driving old trucks / lorries from the UK to various African countries for charity.  I might be interested in trying this but my searches for more detail have been unsuccessful.  My son might like to join me.

Only light trucks as I have just a car licence.  I think that I am limited to 3.5 ton with a fixed wheel base.  Some of the volunteers in the programme had just regular licences.

Unfortunately, my son's licence is slightly more limited than mine but we could research addressing that if necessary.

Has anyone heard of such a scheme?

Clarification: I am not asking for help planning this trip but for help identifying the charities that might want it.  I am not aiming at a specific destination but trying to remember where the demand was.

Comment: What is your route ? Considering the current security scenario there will be loads of hassles (exiting UK and EU), be prepared for that.

Comment: @DumbCoder I don't quite agree.  UK to France should be easy, and Spain to Morocco shouldn't be too much of an issue either, and Morocco is Africa.

Comment: @DumbCoder Questions like that are why I was hoping to do it with an organised charity.  I was hoping that they would be able to advise and assist.  I would not expect UK to France to be a hassle as we are still (for a little longer) in the EU.  I would not attempt such a project without some support.

Comment: @gerrit On what basis you don't agree ? Have you done the journey recently ? The path you mention, on the keyboard, seems easy, but driving a lorry across international borders isn't so seamless. And the person has to return back too.

Comment: @DumbCoder I don't doubt that the procedures will be complex (except maybe not UK to France) but, as I said, I am not considering this as an individual project.  I was hoping that an organisation would help with the paperwork.  Morocco is unlikely to be the final destination and the border crossings within Africa will probably be the hardest.  I am hoping that coming home will be easy: get on a plane.

Comment: You could contact any of the organizations/inviduals doing the same. Some of them can be found with a Google search on your question title ([example](http://vetericyn.com/uk-veterinarians-driving-supplies-to-africa-to-support-gambia-horse-and-donkey-trust/))
and don't forget to look around on travel websites like [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g293794-i9249-k3620056-Driving_to_The_Gambia-Gambia.html)

Comment: @JanDoggen Thanks.  I did not repeat my search today, I should have, but I had tried previously without success.  I can now see a number of hits.  Not sure why I failed before when it has worked just now.

Comment: I had a friend who did this except he shipped the vehicles on boats; it was great fun so be sure to check out that angle also

Comment: @GayotFow Thanks.  I am quite flexible on the route.  What I want to find is a suitable charity to work with: one that has some to me and who is able and willing to assist with the paperwork.  I am fairly flexible on the charity provided that it is not arms or drugs (of the illegal sort).  Legal (medical) drugs would be an attractive cargo but I guess that the paperwork would be even more challenging.

Comment: I think this is a valid enough question to warrant not closing. Either way, keep in mind that if you're thinking of doing this 'for charity', your money would be much better spent not driving a car/truck to wherever you want to take it.

Comment: @MastaBaba I am not specifying a destination (okay, I said Africa but that is rather large).  The programme that I saw suggested that there was a demand for this.  I was hoping that someone else remembered it and would be able to help me identify it.

Comment: My point is that most, if not all, charity projects that end up donating, or selling below cost, products in developing countries (or anywhere, for that matter), tend to undercut local markets and thus hurt the local economy. Read the following to get an idea: http://content.time.com/time/world/article/0,8599,1987628,00.html

Comment: In the 1970s, some Germans bought trucks from the army and drove them to Africa for a missionary society. See http://diguna.de/wir/geschichte/

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me you are thinking of the [Plymouth-Banjul challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plymouth-Banjul_Challenge).

From Wikipedia:

> The Plymouth-Banjul Challenge or unofficially the Ultimate Banger
>   Challenge and previously known as the Plymouth-Dakar Challenge, is an
>   annual car event for charity. It is not a race or a competition as its
>   website states. It was first run in 2003 to Dakar and since 2005 to
>   Banjul. It very roughly follows the route of the more famous Dakar
>   Rally, visiting many of the same countries.

Other candidates are [The Crumball Rally](http://www.crumballrally.com), [The Mongol Rally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongol_Rally) and [Mongolia Charity Rally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolia_charity_rally).

Comment: I don't think it's that since I am fairly sure that the one that I was thinking about involved trucks.  Nonetheless, it is interesting.

Comment: Added another candidate.

Comment: Again, maybe not what I was thinking of but again very interesting.  Thanks.